# Suitable data type to save pointer to numpy ndarray elements

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

For a python project I have the tasks to combine the work of two colleagues and call their functions.
To break the problem down to its essence, consider this scenario:

Colleague A calculates the position and velocity values of objects in his module "body_class.py" that looks something like this:

```
class Body:
def __init__(self, x, y, z, vx, vy, vz):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
    self.vx = vx
    self.vy = vy
    self.vz = vz
```

For other functions that he programmed he would like to keep the code as clean as possible and call the components of the position and speed vectors by their respective names. For this reason he saved them as individual variables.

Colleague B needs to use the position and velocity values of all **Body** objects for some calculations that are time-critical, so he decided to use numpy ndarrays to enable faster matrix computations. The input he expects for his work is a 2D numpy ndarray that contains all the position & velocity components of all **Body** objects in the form of (example for three **Body** objects):

```
state = np.array([[2, 0, 3, -2, 0, -3], #Body 1
                 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],    #Body 2
                 [0, 5, 2, 4, 3, 2]])   #Body 3
```

Is there a way to combine code clarity of using object-oriented instance variables for the operations of colleague A with the efficiency advantages of numpy for the calculations of colleague B?
My initial idea was to save the ndarray containing the position & velocity information for all objects as a class variable of the class **Body** (so that colleague B can easily access this variable "state") similar to this:

```
class Body:
states = np.empty([0,6])
def __init__(self, x, y, z, vx, vy, vz):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
    self.vx = vx
    self.vy = vy
    self.vz = vz
    Body.states = np.concatenate((self.states, np.array([[self.x, self.y, self.z, self.vx, self.vy, self.vz]])), axis=0)
```

...and to then create an instance variable for each Body object that contains just a pointer / reference to the respective ndarray element (so that colleague A can access the variables by e.g. calling *self.x* from inside the class without having to constantly update both this instance variable and the corresponding ndarray element), but I don't know if this is possible to implement in Python, let alone if that would be a good solution for this situation or if the best solution would be to just go for one of both possibilities (ndarray VS instance variables)

Any idea and advice is welcome! Thanks in advance for your help!

UPDATE:

The project is a simulation, so the two actions described above are performed in every time step of the simulation which makes performance an issue.
So I am looking for a solution that makes it possible to store the position & velocity values of all Body objects directly in one big 2D array (which is the required input for colleague B) while still making it possible to access them by their object instance name (e.g. b1.x) or another more meaningful name rather than having to use array indices such as state[3,2].

What I would like to prevent is having to set the position & velocity values for each Body instance in their instance attributes first and then having to construct the big 2D array "state" in every time step again by looping over all the Body instances and stacking their individual position & velocity values together (as for my understanding this would be quite detrimental for performance, but please correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: does Body implement anything else besides storing values?

Comment: Yeah, Body has a lot of other attributes as well as other functions

Comment: The best idea that I've seen is to use the `numpy` arrays as primary storage, and provide the class(es) with methods and indices for accessing their own values in the arrays.  But as a rule, `numpy` does not play nicely with an extensive OOP perspective.  Except of course that `numpy.ndarray` is a highly developed class in its own right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a named tuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Body = namedtuple('Body', ['x', 'y', 'z', 'vx', 'vy', 'vz'])
b1 = Body(2,0,3,-2,0,3)

# now it is possible to access attributes both by name...
b1.x  # returns 2
# ... and as an array
np.array(b1)  # array([ 2,  0,  3, -2,  0,  3])
```

UPD: subclassing and tracking object instances PoC

```
_Body = namedtuple('Body', ['x', 'y', 'z', 'vx', 'vy', 'vz'])

class Body(_Body): 
    instances = set() 
 
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs): 
        body = super(Body, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs) 
        Body.instances.add(body) 
        return body 
         
    def __del__(self): 
        Body.instances.remove(self) 
         
    def xy(self): 
        return self.x + self.y 

    @classmethod 
    def states(cls):
        # will return a 2D numpy array of all Body instances
        return np.array(list(cls.instances))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will look into namedtuples. I didn't know about them. For constructing the ndarray "states" that contains all of the values of all of the bodies I would have to loop over all Body objects with this possibility after creating them, right? Or is there a possibility to do it faster?

Comment: `namedtuples` don't help with the `numpy` interface.

Comment: @hpaulj they will not eliminate the problem completely, but they will definitely make things easier

Comment: @diamon it is possible to subclass from a namedtuple to implement other methods, too. I'm not sure however, what do you mean by looping over all Body - do you need to keep track of all created objects of this type?

Comment: My impression is that the OP wants an array (or arrays) that contain the values for many of these objects.  Some try to make object dtype arrays of the objects, but the result is no better (and maybe worse) than a list of the objects.

Comment: @Marat Sorry, I should have elaborated on this aspect a bit more in my question. I added an update to explain what I mean by looping over the Body instances. I hope that makes it clear?

Comment: @Marat I managed to build a working script out of your PoC. Looks really promising! Thanks so much, you helped me a lot! I will try to implement this in my project and see if its performs faster than my naive approach to loop over all Body instances to construct the 2D ndarray